# A word for a singular/plural homonym?

Tags: single-word-requests, homonyms

Wikipedia tells me that *indicia* is the plural of *indicium* meaning an indication or sign :

> Harry Potter names, characters and related indicia are copyright.

But *indicia* is also :

> A preprinted marking on a mailpiece which shows that postage has been paid by the sender.

(The plural of *indicia* - in this case - is *indicias*, apparently.)

[Wikipedia](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/indicia#English)

Thus one homonym is singular and the other is plural.

Is there a term for this and are there any other examples of this in English ?

Comment: I would say the second is a bastardisation of the first word. Like a QR code consists of QR markings

Comment: @mplungjan So they muddled it up, using the plural 'indicia' instead of the singular 'indicium' and then just invented yet another plural 'indicias' out of thin air ? Not very clever of them.

Comment: But it makes sense: [this postal indicia](http://aristosmail.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/06/CPPM_SD_E.png) has many indicia showing it has been paid :)

Comment: @mplungjan Are you saying that an indicia is the whole QR code ? Or are you saying that each little black square is an indicia ?

Comment: I was using a poor example. The second one is better. It has the name of the postal service, a QR code, it is personal etc. Many indicia (markings) on one indicia (postal thing)

Comment: @mplungjan OK, yes. Now I get it. So there was a confusion about whether 'indicia' was singular or plural in the first place.

Comment: I am not an expert but in this specific case, I am sure the collection became singular since it is on one sticker.

Comment: Uh… really? Nigel, could you firswt name anyone who might, or any situation in which anyone might use any of that in English rather than Latin or Wikipedic?

Comment: medium/media; media/mediae (anatomy)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you describe could be (tentatively) called a "semantic singularization of plural words", i.e. the fact that plural words may, by assimilation drift to a singular meaning. Since the "-a" form in plural is not common in English, and rather sounds like a singular, it is all the more likely to occur.

Hence *[indicia](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=indicia)*, plural form ultimately from Latin *[index](https://www.ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=index)*. The word also exists in English, and does its job as a singular of indicia:

> Something that reveals or indicates; a sign: "Her face ... was a fair
>   index to her disposition" (Samuel Butler)..

According to American Heritage it is "Markings on bulk mailings used as a substitute for stamps or cancellations." If your definition uses a singular it is either some kind of simplication by the person who wrote the definition, or a bastardization (which could be considered the same thing).

Note that you have a similar issue with **criterion/criteria** where the form [criteria](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/criteria) has been used as a singular for some time.